# How to accept post request via json on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, api, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a controller which **accepts** both html and json format data. I want to know how to accept the data of json format from the **POST request from the browser's REST client**. **Null values** are getting stored in the database. How to convert Json format data into string to store it in the database? I have used rabl gem to filter json contents. **Ruby on Rails**.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You get JSON as a string? Why convert it to a string again? Could you give some example what the incoming data looks and how you want to store it?

Comment: @thorstenmüller I want to convert Json into string to store it in database. Its storing null values in database. This in my input via post request {
  "name":"test",
  "email":"test@test.com",
  "feedback":"testing"
} and i'm getting output as {
created_at: "2014-02-19T10:46:28Z"
email: null
feedback: null
id: 29
name: null
updated_at: "2014-02-19T10:46:28Z"
}

Comment: Ok, so you want to get single items of the JSON as strings. (Actually you don't exactly want to convert the whole JSON to one string, but more likely the JSON as a hash). You should post your controller code, and please add the params hash as an example, so we can see what actually reaches your server. (btw: you can edit your question)

Comment: @thorstenmüller I have created controller using scaffolding. I don't know how to accept data from post response of json format and store it in database.

Comment: Well, Rails will convert all your data into a hash (Which is what you actually want to use with ActiveRecord). Especially the URL params. It now depends on how your frontend adds these to the POST. Instead of having single params for email and feedback you may get a single string with serialized JSON in a param like say `params[:json_stuff]` which in turn you want to convert to a hash (easy, just use JSON.parse[:json_stuff]). Though for details we would need to exactly know what you get in the params (you could add the line `debug params` to your controller to see this)

Comment: @thorstenmüller Thank you so much. Its working. I had some problem with data type of a field i.e text format on mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the serialize class method:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class

This allows one to easily save the incoming JSON format and parse it to a Hash when retreiving it from the database.

Comment: This most likely is not really what OP wants. It's more like trying to circumvent the problem (where there is not really a problem, since it's easy to convert incoming JSON to a hash and store the results). This way OP would lose the option to search for the email. Serialize only makes sense when this data is more some 'passive' additional info

Comment: Then why not do it the rails way? setup a create action in a resources controller and interpret the incoming JSON string using JSON.parse(), then put it in a model and save it.

Comment: Also combined with strong_params this would be a piece of cake even circumventing model validations.

Comment: yes, the thing is actually easy. But OP seems new to Rails and has problems to find out how these pieces actually work together. See my comments above, I just tried to get him to show what actually is in the params hash and how exactly the incoming JSON looks and with which key it is stored in params. From there it would be easy enough.